# C++ constructor: Initialize local variable before initializer list

Tags: c++

How to store temporary state, needed for the initializer list, in the constructor (on the stack)?

For example, implementing this constructor …

```
// configabstraction.h
#include <istream>

class ConfigAbstraction
{
public:
    ConfigAbstraction(std::istream& input);

private:
    int m_x;
    int m_y;
    int m_z;
};
```

… using a stateful helper class like this?

```
// mysillyparserdontworry.h
#include <json/reader.h> //jsoncpp

class MySillyParserDontWorry
{
public:
    MySillyParserDontWorry(std::istream& input) { input >> m_parseTree; }
    int intByName(const char* name) const { return m_parseTree[name].asInt(); }

private:
    Json::Value m_parseTree;
};
```

My attempt:

```
// configabstraction.cpp

ConfigAbstraction::ConfigAbstraction(std::istream& input)
    : local_parserState(input) // init local variable first: Not possible!
    , m_a(local_parserState.intByName("a"))
    , m_b(local_parserState.intByName("b"))
    , m_c(local_parserState.intByName("c"))
{
    MySillyParserDontWorry local_parserState; // ...because it is local
}
```

Comment: Make it a member variable?

Comment: Is there a reason you just don't assign the variables in the constructor body?

Comment: @NathanOliver: You cannot initialise them in the body. You can only assign them there. Which is possible in this case but not if the members were `const`.

Comment: @ChristianHackl Oops.  fixed my comment to say assign instead of initialize.

Comment: *"What an artificial limitation of C++!"* - This "artificial limitation" exists in **every** programming language I know (except of those which do not have custom types with constructors in the first place). It does not seem to keep anyone from writing good, effective and readable code.

Comment: To be fair, what I said isn't really true for Java constructors. The Java equivalent of this "artificial limiation" would be trying to access local variables in the class definition (`private final int x = localVariableInConstructor.f();`).

Comment: @ChristianHackl Ah, I begin to see. It's a reflection feature of Java?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: No, reflection has nothing to do with it. It's just that in Java, initialisation can be postponed until first use, i.e. you can even leave `final` (~= `const`) variables uninitialised for a while, and this flexibility extended to fields initialised in a constructor. (Just to clarify: that `private final int x = localVariableInConstructor.f();` is an example of something that would **not** work in Java.)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: This feature indirectly makes more sense in Java due to the `finally` construct, which in turn is not needed in C++ due to destructors. It all comes down to the fact that different programming languages are, well, *different*... :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With C++11 you could solve this with delegating constructors:

```
class ConfigAbstraction
{
public:
    ConfigAbstraction(std::istream& input);

private:
    ConfigAbstraction(const MySillyParserDontWorry& parser);

    int m_a;
    int m_b;
    int m_c;
};

ConfigAbstraction::ConfigAbstraction(const MySillyParserDontWorry& parser)
    : m_a{parser.intByName("a")}
    , m_b{parser.intByName("b")}
    , m_c{parser.intByName("c")}
{
}

ConfigAbstraction::ConfigAbstraction(std::istream& input)
    : ConfigAbstraction{MySillyParserDontWorry{input}}
{
}
```

Comment: You might want to make the other constructor private.

Comment: @ChristianHackl yeah, I considered it but it seems reasonable that someone might want to call it directly in this example.

Comment: That's interesting... I would argue that it makes the class harder to use because it forces users to make a choice whose consequences are hard to understand.

Comment: @ChristianHackl true, I could go either way on it so I made the edit you suggest.

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply doing the assignments in the constructor's body then?

```
ConfigAbstraction::ConfigAbstraction(std::istream& input)
    : m_a(0)
    , m_b(0)
    , m_c(0)
{
    MySillyParserDontWorry local_parserState;
    m_a = local_parserState.intByName("a");
    m_b = local_parserState.intByName("b");
    m_c = local_parserState.intByName("c");
}
```

Is there any specific requirement that hinders you doing that?

---

> *What an artificial limitation of C++!*

It's not an *artificial limitation*. How should initialisation of local variables be done outside of their function's scope? It would just lead to a great confusion, where variables are actually initialised (naming conflicts aside).

Comment: *"It would just lead to a great confusion, where variables are actually initialised"* - Welcome to the world of badly written Java constructors :)

Comment: @ChristianHackl Well, badly written code is bad. Does Java actually compile such stuff and throws runtime exceptions? I'm not well versed with Java.

Comment: In Java, you could write a class like `class X { private final int i; X() { int j = 1; i = j; } }`. The compiler even disallows uses of `i` before its initialisation (or "assignment"). It's 100% safe and correct, but I personally think it's a rather confusing feature. Perhaps that's also my C++ background, though.

Comment: If the initializers can be omitted, as in this case with only plain old data members, I think yes. But they are not generally avoidable; I believe the compiler will sneak in any default constructors left out in the initializer list. I updated the question so that using an initializer list is part of the goal.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution to your problem would be packing the three individual `int`s into a common data structure. This would allow you to initialise an object of that type with a private static helper function. Being able to initialise the object instead of assigning to it later also allows for it to be `const` (if that is required).

Here is an example with `std::tuple`. But you could also create your own helper `struct` or even `std::array<int, 3>`; the basic idea remains the same: **have one member object instead of three.**

```
#include <istream>
#include <tuple>

class MySillyParserDontWorry
{
public:
    MySillyParserDontWorry(std::istream& input) { /* ... */  }
    int intByName(const char* name) const { return /* ... */ 0; }

};

class ConfigAbstraction
{
public:
    ConfigAbstraction(std::istream& input);

private:

    static std::tuple<int, int, int> parse(std::istream& input)
    {
        std::tuple<int, int, int> result;
        MySillyParserDontWorry parser(input);
        std::get<0>(result) = parser.intByName("a");
        std::get<1>(result) = parser.intByName("b");
        std::get<2>(result) = parser.intByName("c");
        return result;
    }

    std::tuple<int, int, int> const m;
};


ConfigAbstraction::ConfigAbstraction(std::istream& input)
    : m(parse(input))
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not initialize local variables bedfore members. The reason for this is very simple (so that it is NOT an artificial limitation):

Members have to be initialized (constructed) before constructor body begins, because constructor body might access them - and they need to be initialized for this access. On the other hand, local variables do not exist before code enters constructor body (as for any other function).
Conclusion - initialization of local variables before members is impossible.

Comment: I believe the memory for local variables is allocated before the code of the initializer list is executed. I call it artificial that C++ prevents using this memory for this code's own purpose.